# Show right node revision for View Draft, View Publised links

Tags: views, panels, workbench

I am using panels to override node template and on panels I am adding views blocks for the node content. I have workbench moderation enabled for this node. Issue is in showing the appropriate revision of node for workbench for example

- When I use `View published` or `View Draft` link, I am seeing all revisions of node field instead of current revision for `View Draft` and published revision for `View published`.

The view I have created is on base table: `node_revision` and fields I am adding are `Content (historical data)`. from panel I am passing `Revision ID` as context to view and in view I have contextual filter set as `Content revision: Nid`

Do I need to create two separate views display filtered by `Workbench moderation : current` and `Workbench moderation : published` and switch between them on basis of URL having draft or not?

Answer (score 1):

Make a clone of the view that workbench itself uses, and use that as a base to work from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'Content revision' relationship on the field to get the correct link to the node.

Also make sure you have the correct relationship, there's two which both have the same name but are on different fields (nid and vid). There's an [issue here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1754354) that descibes the naming problem of these two relationships. The one on the nid is the one to use as it brings in all of the revisions for each node.

Then you can add a filter to the view to only show the current state (Workbench moderation : current).